# Invalid Integer Value DB Port In Digital Ocean Apps Platform

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean

I am currently have problem on my deployment side which is when I run the php artisan migrate:refresh it gives of

**SQLSTATE[08006] [7] invalid integer value "${db.PORT}" for connection option "port" (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')**

**Hosting:**

Digital Ocean

**Platform:**

Laravel Latest Version

**Environment Variables Setup:**

[image: Environment Setup]

Comment: did you solve this ?? I am facing the same problem for the port number